# Best way to append data and resubmit a GET request

Tags: javascript, get, forms

I have a search results page that comes out as a result of a GET request. I want to append some more GET data and reload the page with that information. What is the best method to do so?

Right now i have these two ideas,

1. Keep the previous form data in hidden inputs and just resubmit the data.
2. Manually append the serialized data to the GET string, and request a new page.

Is there any other better way? I feel like the above are sorta dirty, and want to use as less JS as i can, if possible.

(I'm sure this has been asked many times before, but couldn't find a real answer by searching. sorry).

Comment: Why not simply use visible input/select fields? I obviously don't know your exact application, but showing the currently active search parameters on the search result page seems like a good idea. The user see, what the current settings are, they can change the parameters, add new search options and submit the search form again.

Comment: the new data to be appended are more like filters. So the user doesn't really search again, just filter the results. And i want to submit that filter information to the server by appending more info the the GET string... I don't want to display the search form again.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with hidden input fields for each parameter already set.

They should be used if [a value that is not intended to be examined or manipulated by the user](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#hidden-state-%28type=hidden%29), which is what you want. Put those in your filter `<form>` and resubmit them together with all the newly selected parameters. This gives you a nice URL that you can share and revisit.

For what it's worth: other answers I found suggest the same solution.